# Escaping quote in JavaScript and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, string, escaping

```
<?php
    /* ... Getting record from database */

    $comment = $record["comment"];
    /* There might be quotes or double quotes, we don't know */

    echo "<input type='button' onclick=\"doSomething('$comment')\" />";
?>

<script>
    function doSomething(comment) {
        alert(comment);

        /* Something else */
    }
</script>
```

When $comment string contains a single quote , I'm getting "**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL**" error in javascript.

- I add slashes before quotes, it didn't work - `$comment = str_replace("'","\'",$comment);`

How can I escape quote and double quote in this example?

Comment: Not relevant with the php error but You're missing closing '>' of <input tag

Comment: @Birey,@Bakudan sorry i didn't copy the code, write it here, and missed the "/>" tag and a double quote. now I edited it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [json_encode()](http://php.net/json_encode), which guarantees your output will be syntactically valid JavaScript code:

```
<input type="button" onclick="doSomething(<?php echo json_encode($comment) ?>">
```

Comment: I can't use that also, because multibyte extension is not enable,thanks anyway. the best way.

Answer (score 2):

Use the PHP function [addslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php).

Comment: what is the differences betwwen str_replace("'","\'","comment bla bla") ?

Comment: addslashes() puts a backslash in front of any character that needs it.  You don't have to worry about what needs it and what doesn't, it just does it.

Comment: addslashes is a moronically bad function. It HAPPENS to kinda work for javascript, but only because JS's escaping requirements are relatively close to what addslashes does.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this in Javascript:

```
function addslashes(str){
    str=str.replace(//g,'\');
    str=str.replace(/'/g,''');
    str=str.replace(/"/g,'"');
    str=str.replace(//g,'');
    return str;
}
function stripslashes(str){
    str=str.replace(/'/g,''');
    str=str.replace(/"/g,'"');
    str=str.replace(//g,'');
    str=str.replace(/\/g,'');
    return str;
}
```

Hope this help :)